# Can I use the pipe and update syntax together with structs?

Tags: elixir

I'm finding I want to update a struct pretty often, then pipe the result to another function. The need to update my struct keeps breaking up my pipes.

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
my_struct = %{my_struct | my_field_in_struct: a_new_value} |> my_funct1
my_struct = %{my_struct | my_field_in_struct: a_new_value} |> my_funct2 
my_struct = %{my_struct | my_field_in_struct: a_new_value} |> my_funct3
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
my_struct
|> %{ | my_field_in_struct: a_new_value}
|> my_funct1
|> %{ | my_field_in_struct: a_new_value}
|> my_funct2
|> %{ | my_field_in_struct: a_new_value}
|> my_funct3
```

The original syntax may not be all that bad, but still.

I know I can use *Map.put()*, but then I would have to write a function in my module to convert the resulting map back to my struct type.

Has anyone run into this tiny annoyance before? Is there a clean alternative?

Comment: What’s wrong with [`Map.put/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#put/3) here? Structs are bare `Map`s underneath and `Map.put/3` will preserve a `__struct__` key.

Comment: "I know I can use Map.put(), but then I would have to write a function in my module to convert the resulting map back to my struct type." No you won't. You can use `Map.put` on any struct and as long as you don't modify the `__struct__` field, you'll get back a struct. (A struct is nothing more than a map with a `__struct__` field.)

Comment: Oh, you're right! I'm not sure why I didn't think that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map.replace!/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#replace!/3) now. It uses [:maps.update/3](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#update-3) under the hood, which is equivalent to the `%{struct | field: value}` syntax.

Answer (score 6):

What is really great about Elixir, it has macros. So why would not you define your own pipe operator if this is a very common operation for your application?

```rb
defmodule StructPipe do
  defmacro left ~>> right do
    {:%{}, [], [{:|, [], [left, right]}]}
  end
end

defmodule MyStruct do
  defstruct ~w|foo bar baz|a
end

defmodule StructPipe.Test do
  import StructPipe
  def test do
    %MyStruct{foo: 42}
    ~>> [bar: 3.14]
    ~>> [baz: "FOOBAR"]
  end
end

IO.inspect StructPipe.Test.test, label: "Resulting in"
#⇒ Resulting in: %MyStruct{bar: 3.14, baz: "FOOBAR", foo: 42}
```

---

Note that it might be safely mixed with a normal [`Kernel.|>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) pipe:

```rb
%MyStruct{foo: 42}
|> IO.inspect(label: "Ini")
~>> [bar: 3.14, baz: 3.14]
|> IO.inspect(label: "Mid")
~>> [baz: "FOOBAR"]
|> IO.inspect(label: "Aft")

#⇒ Ini: %MyStruct{bar: nil, baz: nil, foo: 42}
#  Mid: %MyStruct{bar: 3.14, baz: 3.14, foo: 42}
#  Aft: %MyStruct{bar: 3.14, baz: "FOOBAR", foo: 42}
```

Comment: Defining `use` for a module that simply imports that module is an anti-pattern. Tell users to just `import` the module instead. :)

Comment: Also note that `~>>` doesn't need to be a macro. It could be a function too: `def left ~>> right, do: Enum.into(right, left)`.

Comment: @JoséValim [`Enum.into/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2) requires `Collectable` which is not implemented for structs by default. Thanks, `import` instead of `use` is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could also pass in an anonymous function if you *really* wanted to:

```
my_struct
|> (&(%{ &1| my_field_in_struct: a_new_value})).()
```

or

```
my_struct
|> (fn struct -> %{ struct| my_field_in_struct: a_new_value} end).()
```

but I don't think that looks very great / readable